# How can TRY CATCH be organized in C# such that console will show what error it is?

Tags: c#

I would like to reflect the what kind of error user have if the user enters a string char instead of int.

I have tried this, however did not find what I should be using for the expectation above.

```
 Console.Write("Pls enter your age: ");
ageAgain:
    try
    {
        int yas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Thx, i'll keep it!!");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You've made a mistake, re-enter your age: ");
        goto ageAgain;
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Use `int.TryParse` instead of cathing the exception with `int.Parse`. If `TryParse` returns `false` you know that the user did not enter an `int`.

Comment: are you familiar with the [Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/) object ? it encapsulates error details...

Comment: _Do not use goto_. Delete it from your code and from your memory. Forget that C# supports it. We will never talk about it again. Yes, there are _very rare and specialized_ usecases for it. You will probably not have one in your carreer, unless you specialize in a field where that's going to be the case.

Comment: _"I would like to reflect the what kind of error user have if the user enters a string char instead of int"_ - so, would it be enough to say something along "What you typed in was not a valid number." or do you really want to tell the user _exactly_ what they did wrong? I mean e.g. Input = "123asdf" => "'asdf' is not valid input" ?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods 

I would prefer to have this one: "Input = "123asdf" => "'asdf' is not valid input" 

However, I guess I found a way to categorize and see what kind of error I have on the console like this: **`catch (DivideByZeroException ex) `** => **`Console.WriteLine(ex.Message )`**
Besides this, **`catch (Exception ex) `**  is like a more common pool for this kind of message on the console. What do you think?

Comment: It's not about what I think. It's about what you need to do. In general, what most people would do is use `TryParse` and just output an error message. Flow by Exception is a common anti pattern. That's why I would recommend to train early on to only use it for truely exceptional cases. Anticipating a typo from a user when you cannot force a certain type of input is to be expected, not exceptional.

Comment: `DivideByZeroException` sounds like you got some extra code that's not shown, there. This cannot possibly be thrown on parsing the input. Just as a sidenote.

Answer (score 0):

There is nearly never a good reason to use label and goto in production code.
So let's use a loop and just keep asking for valid input, using an exception-less approach:

```
public int AskAge() // maybe static, too
{
    Console.Write("Pls enter your age: ");
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var age))
    {
        Console.Write("You've made a mistake, re-enter your age: ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Thx, i'll keep it!!");
    return age;
}
```

Just as a starting point. You may want to consider ...

- cancellation
- stating the *expected* input (e.g. "Valid inputs are integer number between X and Y inclusive.")

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like Tim suggested in the comments and use `TryParse` like this:

```
private void AskQuestionTryParse()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your age: ");

Getdata:
    int age;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks!");
        // Do something with the data here
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The data you entered is not a number! Please try again.");
        goto Getdata;
    }
}
```

Using `TryParse` in this case is ideal as it makes your code shorter and is sufficient for this case.

You can also use a classical `Try/Catch` block like this:

```
private void AskQuestionTryCatch()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your age: ");

Getdata:
    
    try
    {
        Int age;
        age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks!");
        // Do something with the data here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There was an error parsing the data you entered! {ex.Message}");
        goto Getdata;
    }
}
```

Which in this case is not really needed. The only error you will face in this code is that the user enters something other than numbers. Which a `TryParse` is made for, thus the `Try/Catch` block here is "overkill".